# Can't Understand C++ Function Declaration

Tags: c++

I was reading through the source code of a program written in C++ when I came across a few function declarations like this:

`virtual bool _Open(LPCTSTR aFileSpec, DWORD &aFlags) = 0;`

Why is this declared function being set equal to zero?

Additional Question: (Edit)

What would a statement like this mean?

`virtual __int64 _Length() const = 0;`

What other keywords could replace `const`, and what would they mean?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Open`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. The person wrote that code is playing with fire.

Comment: @PeteBecker • It takes a child playing with fire to raze a village.

Comment: @PeteBecker: What does "reserved for use by the implementation" mean?  What is the "implementation"?

Comment: @10101100 — “the implementation” refers to the compiler and its version of the standard library. Nobody else should define names like that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pure virtual function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class

Deriving non-abstract classes are expected to implement it.